# How to fix 'expected identifier or '(' before 'int'' error in a struct returning function

Tags: c

I am creating C code to output diameter, area, circumference from a single function.
I am using a structure to output the data. However, on creation of a function that outputs a struct, I am getting the following error: 'expected identifier or '(' before 'int''

I have tried doing the obvious that the code says, but to no avail.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct circle
{
    int diameter;
    int area;
    int circumference;
};
    typedef struct circle one;

struct properties (int r)
{
    struct circle.one.diameter = 2 * r;
    struct circle.one.area = (22 * r * r) / 7;
    struct circle.one.circumference = (2 * 22 * r) / 7;

    return (one);
}

int main ()
{
    int a;
    int result;
    printf ("text");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    result = properties (a);
    printf ("%d%d%d", result );

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be the values of diameter, area, circumference.

Comment: `struct properties (int r)` does not compile. It is neither a `struct` not a function definition.

Comment: Your function is missing the return type; according to the code in main, it should return an int.

Comment: `printf ("%d%d%d", result );` is missing two arguments, but that's the least of your problems here

Comment: It's also unclear what `struct circle.one.<member> = <value>` is supposed to do. Perhaps you need reread your tutorial(s) on using C structs again.

Comment: Are you really approximating *pi* to `22/7`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Which, of course, is 3.

Comment: @WeatherVane Giving the code, that should be good enough. Especially since it's integer division anyway.

Comment: This need many corrections. better to use the pass by reference concept here, pass a structure pointer to the function that is calculating the properties. your function declaration will look as "void properties (struct circle *sCircle, int r);" then calculate and assign the value as part of definition of this function. from main pass the address of the structure so that it will get a proper information.

Comment: @Bathsheba 3 [by law?](https://io9.gizmodo.com/the-eccentric-crank-who-tried-to-legislate-the-value-of-5880792)

Comment: Guys! i know the value of pi! I am more concerned about the error I can't fix!

Comment: @VarunKhanna: One of the issues **is the fact that you use 22 / 7**. (Integer division).

Comment: @VarunKhanna: you can resolve this one compilation error by making the definition as "struct circle *properties (int r);" or "void properties (struct circle *sCircle, int r);", your function declaration is not proper causing this error, but you will have many more compilation and logical error. that you may have to resolve. and change the main() accordingly to call the function.

Comment: Thank's guys!! I will fix the code including the pi problem and post it here for you guys!

Answer (score 2):

This is the working program with numerous errors corrected. Note that it is doing integer division, so the results are rounded down to the nearest integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct circle
{
    int diameter;
    int area;
    int circumference;
};

typedef struct circle one;

one properties (int r)                          // use the typedef
{
    one calcs;                                  // define a struct
    calcs.diameter = 2 * r;                     // clean up the act
    calcs.area = (22 * r * r) / 7;
    calcs.circumference = (2 * 22 * r) / 7;

    return calcs;
}

int main (void)                                 // full definition
{
    int a;
    one result;                                 // this should be a struct
    printf ("radius: ");                        // sensible prompt
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    result = properties (a);
    // space separate the output, pass each value
    printf ("%d %d %d", result.diameter, result.area, result.circumference);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
radius: 3
6 28 18
```

Comment: Try 355 / 113 instead of 22 / 7; that's good to 6 significant figures in floating point arithmetic.